Android app with accessibility service; should I use a boot receiver?
In my Android application, I use the accessibility service for certain tasks. My question is, will the service be started automatically after the phone reboot, or should I use the broadcast receiver, i.e., the boot receiver, so that the OS starts my application and the accessibility service after the phone reboot?
